# How to delete all data leaving a pair of values ​in hstore PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am having the data of the name column as below :

```
"name:en"=>"Mường Tè district", "name:ko"=>"므엉떼", "name:vi"=>"TT. Mường Tè", "name:zh"=>"芒齐市镇", "official_name"=>"Thị trấn Mường Tè", "official_name:en"=>"Muong Te Town"
```

name column has data type hstore in postgresql.

Is there a way to keep a pair of values ​​eg leaving only the value pair "name:vi"=>"TT.Mường Tè" ? (delete all value pairs leaving the value pair "name:vi"=>"TT.Mường Tè" ). I want to make 1 query to solve the above problem, thanks !

Comment: What should happen if there is no `name:vi` key?

Comment: @Bergiall rows of the name column have ```name:vi```

Comment: Have you look at the [`hstore` operators and functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html#id-1.11.7.25.6)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`slice` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE) does just that:

```
UPDATE the_table
SET name = slice(name, ARRAY['name:vi'])
```